# I can't find python package fftw3

Tags: python, fftw, pyfftw

I'm trying to use fftw3 on python to compute ffts really fast (using all my cores!)
The problem is... I can't find the fftw3 package for python... 
I know it exists because the function I need uses it if and only if it's installed.

This is the module that I use: https://github.com/keflavich/image_tools/blob/master/fft_psd_tools/convolve_nd.py

And as expected this is what I get if I try to import it:

```
>>> import fftw3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fftw3
>>>
```

And I've tried this:

```
sudo pip install fftw3
sudo apt-get install python-fftw3
sudo easy_install fftw3
```

And I have also tried googling for its location, or installation instructions, with nothing to be found!

I am also aware that fftw is a C library and that pyfftw exists as python wrappers for that package, but the function I use utilizes fftw3.

I am hoping someone could point me to where this module is located!

P.S. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and I'm using python 2.7. I also tried importing it in python 3 but it's not there either.

Comment: Did you install it? This package does not come with Python.

Comment: What I mean is I can't find the installation for this package... Maybe I'm an idiot, I've been searching for the past 2 hours!

Comment: I believe you should `pip install pyfftw3` because that is the name of the package on PyPI. Then try `import fftw3`. (Note the name of the top level module does not necessarily have to match the name of the package.)

Comment: Are you getting an error message from `pip`?

Comment: It says I already have the requirement satisfied, but I believe that's because pyfftw3 is the package pyfftw? Which isn't the same as fftw3.

Comment: Also @Will If I try to install fftw3 I get the does not exist error...

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question as being about "general computing hardware and software" seems to have absolutely no idea what this question is about.

Comment: Damn... so now people can't answer my question :(?

Comment: Hmm I got it installed with `sudo pip install pyfftw3` and then in python `import fftw3`.  I'm on Linux Mint Debian 2.

Comment: Thank you Will! So... To solve my issue I removed the pyfftw3 package and then I reinstalled again and now I can import fftw3. Bizarre...
 I'm really sorry about this, I didn't think this could be an issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the problem was with the package you were trying to `pip`.  I had no errors with `sudo pip install pyfftw3` then `import fftw3`

```
will@will-mint2 ~ $ sudo pip install pyfftw3
[sudo] password for will: 
Downloading/unpacking pyfftw3
  Downloading PyFFTW3-0.2.1.tar.gz
  ...
  Successfully installed pyfftw3
Cleaning up...
will@will-mint2 ~ $ python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Mar  1 2015, 12:57:24) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fftw3
>>> exit()
```

Comment: Thanks! I just had to reinstall it. 
I had no idea that would be causing the issue!

Comment: Glad it's working!  Have fun fast fourier transforming!

Answer (score 2):

For windows

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyfftw

install it by:

```
pip install [filename].whl
```

import in your code by

```
import pyfftw as fftw
```